# which is the best way to create multilingual facebook landing page?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-page

I would like to create a multilanguage landing page , 
users will get the content according to their chosen language.

I would like the landing page to have a design and a contact form

can i do this using static html app ? or is there any other way to doing that ?

Thanks

Comment: "users will get the content according to their chosen language."  Which chosen?  The one of their OS that their web browser sends in the Http Request?  Or their settings in their Facebook account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the user authorizes your app you should receive a *signed request* from facebook. This request is explained here: [Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).

As part of the data in that signed request, you get the user object which contains *the locale string*.
You can use that locale code in order to get the users' preferred language and act based on that.

The fact that you want to display different things based on language choice means that the content is not static, it's dynamic.
You can just use javascript to auth the user with facebook, get the locale from the signed request, and then load different static html files according to the chosen language.
That way the content itself is static, but the choice is dynamic.

Hope this is what you meant.

Comment: thank you for your reply, well im kinda new to that... and i was planning to use the static html app that is already installed on my page. how can i use your suggetion ?

Comment: I don't fully understand your situation due to the limited information you provided, more than that though is that what you're asking is a bit too wide, you should get a bit more familiar with things and come back with a more specific question(s).

Comment: ok so here is my question after digging around a bit. lets say i have built a php application on my website that will serve content according to the users IP (location tracking) will i be able to use this application as a facebook page , will it behave the same and how can i do that ?

Comment: Language based on ip location is not a good way to go, if I access your app while I visit my sister in japan then I would get your app in Japanese. As I wrote in my original answer, once the user authorizes your app you get what is called "signed request" from facebook, it contains, among other things, the user object which has the locale the user is using in facebook, that is what is the language the user chose for the UI. You should use that in order to decide on the language for the user.

Comment: well can i use the created object using facebook iframe and my external php application ?